# Populate Data Table columns/rows with values?

Tags: vb.net, datatable, export-to-csv

I'm new to Data Tables in VB.net.  I want to create a Data Table with a preset number of rows and columns.  I've got that part down (I think?).  Now I want to populate each of the "cells" in the Data Table with the values that I have.  I've seen example code where they are populating each row with data in each cell as they add the new row.  That is not how I want to do it, nor am I sure I can even do it that way considering my application.  After the Data Table is populated, I want to write it as is to a CSV file.  But that's after I get the Data Table part of it working.

Thanks for the help

```
 Dim bools() As Boolean = New Boolean(10) {testTypeNS, testTypeOR, torqueTypeBreak, torqueTypeFix, sheaveHigh, sheaveLow, _
                                             directionCW, directionCCW, pneuActuateAuto, elecActuateAuto, hydrActuateAuto}
    Dim Presets() As Integer = New Integer(16) {cyclesSP, oilFlowSP, oilTempSP, spindleSpeedSP, accelRateSP, decelRateSP, flowDevAlrmSP, _
                                                oilTempAlrmSP, partTempAlrmSP, exitOilTempAlrmSP, spindleOverrunSP, OverrunHoldTimeSP, _
                                                actuatorOnRpmSp, actuatorOffRpmSP, cycleIncrRpmSP, recordOnRpmSP, recordOffRpmSP}




    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim csv As String = "myfile.csv"

    Dim sourceTable As DataTable = New DataTable()
    sourceTable.Columns.AddRange(New DataColumn() {New DataColumn("BooleanValues", GetType(Boolean)), _
                                                   New DataColumn("IntValues", GetType(Integer)), _
                                                   New DataColumn("singValues", GetType(Single)), _
                                                   New DataColumn("accelVals", GetType(Integer)), _
                                                   New DataColumn("decelVals", GetType(Integer)), _
                                                   New DataColumn("speedVals", GetType(Integer)), _
                                                   New DataColumn("timeVals", GetType(Integer)), _
                                                   New DataColumn("flowVals", GetType(Integer)), _
                                                   New DataColumn("tempVals", GetType(Integer))})

    For i = 0 To 49
        'Add 50 rows to the Data Table
        sourceTable.Rows.Add()
    Next

    For Each [bool] In bools
        'Populate first column of cells in 'sourceTable' with boolean values that are in bools(10) array
    Next

    For Each [integer] In Presets
        'Populate second column of cells in 'sourceTable' with integers that are in Presets(16) array.
    Next

    'etc..  Continue populating the other columns of the DataTable with corresponding array of values
```

Comment: Is there some reason for the DataTable beyond a container for the data?  I am wondering why you chose that.

Comment: No particular reason.  If there's a better way, easier way to do it, then I'm open for suggestions.  I'll admit, I'm not a polished programmer.  Maybe I'm making this more difficult/complicated than what it needs to be?

Answer (score 0):

This was actually pretty easy. The code that converts the Data Table to CSV is not mine.  You can find that [here](http://redsouljaz.com/2010/06/03/vb-net-set-data-table-to-csv-file/).

```
Private Sub SaveRecipeToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveRecipeToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim testTypeNS As Boolean, testTypeOR As Boolean, torqueTypeBreak As Boolean, torqueTypeFix As Boolean, sheaveHigh As Boolean, _
        sheaveLow As Boolean, directionCW As Boolean, directionCCW As Boolean, pneuActuateAuto As Boolean, elecActuateAuto As Boolean, _
        hydrActuateAuto As Boolean
    Dim cyclesSP As Integer, oilFlowSP As Integer, oilTempSP As Integer, spindleSpeedSP As Integer, accelRateSP As Integer, decelRateSP As Integer, _
        flowDevAlrmSP As Integer, oilTempAlrmSP As Integer, partTempAlrmSP As Integer, exitOilTempAlrmSP As Integer, spindleOverrunSP As Integer, _
        OverrunHoldTimeSP As Integer, actuatorOnRpmSp As Integer, actuatorOffRpmSP As Integer, cycleIncrRpmSP As Integer, recordOnRpmSP As Integer, _
        recordOffRpmSP As Integer
    Dim torqueAlrmSP As Single


    cyclesSP = CInt(dgvPresets(1, 0).Value)
    oilFlowSP = CInt(dgvPresets(1, 1).Value)
    oilTempSP = CInt(dgvPresets(1, 2).Value)
    spindleSpeedSP = CInt(dgvPresets(1, 3).Value)
    accelRateSP = CInt(dgvPresets(1, 4).Value)
    decelRateSP = CInt(dgvPresets(1, 5).Value)
    flowDevAlrmSP = CInt(dgvPresets(1, 6).Value)
    oilTempAlrmSP = CInt(dgvPresets(1, 7).Value)
    partTempAlrmSP = CInt(dgvPresets(1, 8).Value)
    exitOilTempAlrmSP = CInt(dgvPresets(1, 9).Value)
    torqueAlrmSP = CSng(dgvPresets(1, 10).Value)
    spindleOverrunSP = CInt(dgvNonSync(1, 0).Value)
    OverrunHoldTimeSP = CInt(dgvNonSync(1, 1).Value)
    actuatorOnRpmSp = CInt(dgvNonSync(1, 2).Value)
    actuatorOffRpmSP = CInt(dgvNonSync(1, 3).Value)
    cycleIncrRpmSP = CInt(dgvNonSync(1, 4).Value)
    recordOnRpmSP = CInt(dgvNonSync(1, 5).Value)
    recordOffRpmSP = CInt(dgvNonSync(1, 6).Value)

    Dim bools() As Boolean = New Boolean(10) {testTypeNS, testTypeOR, torqueTypeBreak, torqueTypeFix, sheaveHigh, sheaveLow, _
                                             directionCW, directionCCW, pneuActuateAuto, elecActuateAuto, hydrActuateAuto}
    Dim Presets() As Integer = New Integer(16) {cyclesSP, oilFlowSP, oilTempSP, spindleSpeedSP, accelRateSP, decelRateSP, flowDevAlrmSP, _
                                                oilTempAlrmSP, partTempAlrmSP, exitOilTempAlrmSP, spindleOverrunSP, OverrunHoldTimeSP, _
                                                actuatorOnRpmSp, actuatorOffRpmSP, cycleIncrRpmSP, recordOnRpmSP, recordOffRpmSP}





    Dim csv As String = "myfile.csv"
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    'Create data table with columns and column names
    Dim sourceTable As DataTable = New DataTable()
    sourceTable.Columns.AddRange(New DataColumn() {New DataColumn("BooleanValues", GetType(Boolean)), _
                                                   New DataColumn("IntValues", GetType(Integer)), _
                                                   New DataColumn("singValues", GetType(Single)), _
                                                   New DataColumn("accelVals", GetType(Integer)), _
                                                   New DataColumn("decelVals", GetType(Integer)), _
                                                   New DataColumn("speedVals", GetType(Integer)), _
                                                   New DataColumn("timeVals", GetType(Integer)), _
                                                   New DataColumn("flowVals", GetType(Integer)), _
                                                   New DataColumn("tempVals", GetType(Integer))})
    'Add rows to the data table
    For i = 0 To 49
        sourceTable.Rows.Add()
    Next

    'Populate first column (called BooleanValues) of cells in the Data Table with the boolean values in the Array
    i = 0
    For Each [bool] In bools
        sourceTable.Rows(i).Item("BooleanValues") = bools(i)
        i += 1
    Next

    'Populate second column (called IntValues) of cells in the Data Table with the integer values n the Array
    i = 0
    For Each [integer] In Presets
        sourceTable.Rows(i).Item("IntValues") = Presets(i)
        i += 1
    Next

    'Populate third column (called singValues) cell in the Data Table with a single variable specified
    i = 0
    sourceTable.Rows(i).Item("singValues") = torqueAlrmSP

    'Populate the remaining columns in the Data Table with the values that are in the DataGridView on the form
    For Each r As DataGridViewRow In dgvStepTest.Rows
        sourceTable.Rows(i).Item("accelVals") = dgvStepTest(0, i).Value
        sourceTable.Rows(i).Item("decelVals") = dgvStepTest(1, i).Value
        sourceTable.Rows(i).Item("speedVals") = dgvStepTest(2, i).Value
        sourceTable.Rows(i).Item("timeVals") = dgvStepTest(3, i).Value
        sourceTable.Rows(i).Item("flowVals") = dgvStepTest(4, i).Value
        sourceTable.Rows(i).Item("tempVals") = dgvStepTest(5, i).Value
        i += 1
    Next

    'Call the 'ConvertToCSV' Sub that converts the DataTable to a CSV and saves it somewhere to disk
    ConvertToCSV(sourceTable, "C:\Users\dmckin01\Desktop\Recipes\test.csv", ",")
End Sub
```